# scroll position in div with master page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, html

i have a div tag within a content tag as i am using a masterpage which has the forms and body tags.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">

  <div id="xxx"  style="overflow:scroll; height:450px;">

     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ...>

     </asp:GridView>

  </div>
</Content>
```

I wish to maintain the scroll position of the div when any postback happens.

There are jscripts when i search for it but i dont know 
how do i apply them with the masterpage.

please help if there is an easier way. or how to use javascript with the above code.

Any help is appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it worked for me.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
    <div id="divScroll" style="overflow:auto; height:450px;">  
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ...>
        </asp:GridView>   
    </div> 
</Content> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);               
</script>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

javascript file add the following code:

```
var scrollTop;
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) 
{
    var m = document.getElementById('divScroll');
    scrollTop = m.scrollTop;
}
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    var m = document.getElementById('divGrid');
    m.scrollTop = scrollTop;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use AJAX to remove postbacks which will keep your position.  More specifically you can take a look at the UpdatePanel control.

**Update:**

A non-AJAX solution would be to add the following attribute in your page tag.

<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>

Comment: yes that is an option but i have many pages in the solution, and my company dont wish to make that change for one and not make for the rest.. in short it is a future project and i need this feature without ajax... thanks for the quick reply though

Comment: Try this: <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>

Comment: i have tried this but it does not work for div it works for tha main scroll of the page..

Comment: How about an iframe then?  Create a separate page with the grid and the page scroll attribute, then place that in the host page's iframe.

Comment: i was looking out for iframes and every1 was like its not a good idea... check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364522/how-do-i-use-frame-on-asp-net-page .. is there no way by using Jscript